# How can I make a RaisedButton shape like this?

Tags: flutter

I want to shape a RaisedButton like this:

[image: Shape of button]

How can i do that ?

```
 ButtonTheme(
        minWidth: 120,
        height: 40.0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          textColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          color: Colors.redAccent,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: new Text("Giriş"),
        ));
```

Comment: ClipPath will help to achieve what you are looking for.
[ClipPath tutorial](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clipping-in-flutter-e9eaa6b1721a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it done by giving [BeveledRectangleBorder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BeveledRectangleBorder-class.html) to the `shape` property...

Here's a minimal example for you..

```dart
shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))
      ),
```

Hope it solves your issue..!